# Retyping Username and Password in Git Bash for Github access

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I recently wrote the wrong username and password to login to my github account through git bash. I originally tried cloning my git branch when it prompted my login with a pop up.

After I got my username and/or password login wrong, when I try cloning again it does not give me the option to login again.

I now cannot type my credentials again.

When I try cloning again it automatically says this:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can have the pop-up appear again so I can re-write my username and password?

Comment: Take a look at https://builditmasters.com/git-config-username-and-password-global/  too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pop up probably saved it in your git configuration. This can be done global or local per repository.

To check if it's within the config use the following commands (for global):

```
git config --global user.name
git config --global user.password
```

or the following commands (for local):

```
git config user.name
git config user.password
```

If either are filled and return your password then you could set it correctly by supplying a value after the git config command:

```
git config --global user.name "yourUsername"
git config --global user.password "yourPassword"
```

or for the local one:

```
git config user.name "yourUsername"
git config user.password "yourPassword"
```

Comment: Thanks. I am going to mark this correct. It is still not working because this is an enterprise account and my login is through an SSO. So it's alittle bit more complex than I thought than a simple username and password. Thanks for the help!

Comment: There is no such setting as [`user.password`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-username). `user.name` and `user.email` are never used for authentication, they're only used for commit metadata.