# What is "git config user.password"?

Tags: git, authentication, config

I've seen `git config user.password` recommended in several Stack Overflow answers as a way to save git user credentials.

[How can I save username and password in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54979082/2234742)

[How to change my Git username in terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51997218/2234742)

[Retyping Username and Password in Git Bash for Github access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55360988/2234742)

However, I can't find any mention of `user.password` in [the Git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), only `user.name` and `user.email`. None of the answers seem to link to a resource on what exactly it does or how to use it.

What is `git config user.password`, and how do you use it? Is it an alternative method for configuring the credential manager, or is it something different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These answers are simply wrong.

Git configuration files will let you set any old thing you like, such as:

```
git config user.aardvark zebra
```

and:

```
git config helicopter.rotor airplane
```

Since nothing *consults* these settings, they have no effect.

Comment: The first two answers are highly upvoted, are you sure?

Comment: Yep. It is, of course, possible to write *your own program* that reads the `helicopter.rotor` setting, and perhaps someone did write one that reads `user.password`, back in the long-ago past.

Comment: (Of course the rotor setting probably should be to a pitch angle, but...)